# JavaScript - string to object?

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to dynamically add categories to JavaScript object from a string. But the problem is that commas inside this string are not recognized as separate items.

So I have this:

```
var prices = json_graph['offer_prices'].join(','); // that returns for example '2,3,4,5'
```

Then I want to use this like so:

```
xAxis: {
  categories: [prices]
}
```

The problem is, that this is recognized as a single item. How can I split this string by commas and add it under categories?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the fact you're using `join` on it, I'd say the `offer_prices` property is an array. So there's no need to turn it into a string (but see below, if you have a reason for doing that you haven't shown):

```
xAxis: {
    categories: json_graph['offer_prices']
}
```

Or if you want to make a copy of it for some reason rather than using the original:

```
xAxis: {
    categories: json_graph['offer_prices'].slice(0) // slice(0) = shallow copy
}
```

If you have a reason for creating the `prices` string and really do want to use it for this, you can do that by splitting it apart using the comma as a delimiter, with `split`:

```
xAxis: {
    categories: prices.split(',')
}
```

---

Side note: You've written `json_graph['offer_prices']` and so that's what I've used above, but if you're *literally* using that in your code, you can just write `json_graph.offer_prices` instead if you want, barring some reason you need not to (you might need the string with some tool or something you're using, I wouldn't know).

Comment: Many thanks for all your support! It now works as expected and you've made me understand why!

Answer (score 1):

```js
categories = prices.split(",");
```

This will split the categories string into several strings using `,` as the separator and return them in an array.